# C - Converting array of char into lower case

Tags: c

Currently I have websites store in char *banned[100] and I want to convert them all into lowercase 
using:

```
char *banned[100];
int x = 0;
if(fgets(temp, 100, file) != NULL) {
        char *tempstore;
        tempstore = (char*) malloc(sizeof(temp));
        strcpy(tempstore, temp);
        banned[x] = tempstore;
        x++;
    }
char temps[100];        
while(banned[c]){
        temps[c]=putchar(tolower(*banned[c]));
        c++;
}
```

But the results are not what I'm expecting. Can I get some tips/hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `putchar()` doing there? What do you *think* it does? Also note that `banned` is an array of 100 `char*` (string) elements, while `temps` is an array of 100 `char` (character) elements. `temps` is a string by itself; it is not an array of strings.

Comment: Ohh I wasnt aware of that.. Thanks for the telling me! I'm still very new to C :P

Answer (score 4):

Since you know the size of the string (char array), you can just use a `for` loop.

```
char temps[100];
size_t i;

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  temps[i] = tolower(temps[i]);
```

Comment: The `if` conditional is redundant; `tolower()` will perform this same test.

Comment: My values are stored in char *banned[100] so that wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: @self Yes. Redundant code is bad. It provides zero benefit while giving bugs a place to hide.

Comment: It's bad idea to convert all chars in temps. You have stop at the last '\0' char.

Comment: Guys, it would be better if you actually update the answer with good suggestions. Most people will never read the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to meet your requirement,

```
char *strtolower(char *s)
{
    char *d = (char *)malloc(strlen(s));
    while (*s)
    {
        *d =tolower(*s);
        d++;
        s++;
    }
    return d;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *banned[100];
    char *temps[100];
    char temp[100];

    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int x = 0;

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(temp, 100, file) != NULL)
        {
            char *tempstore;
            tempstore = (char *) malloc(sizeof(temp));
            strcpy(tempstore, temp);
            banned[x] = tempstore;
            x++;

            puts(tempstore);

        }

        int c = 0;

        while(c < x)
        {
            temps[c] = strtolower(banned[c]);
            puts(temps[c]);
            c++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That would break another piece of my code where I store values into banned:

Comment: what break ? also you need to confirm the string banned is null terminated. That means, the end of string must be marked with '\0'.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant if I changed char *banned[100] to char banned[100], another part of the code will break. I've updated the question with more code. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: you trying to read single entry in file ? or can be many entries ?

Comment: The file can contain up to 100 website urls, which would each be on a different line

Comment: So you will need to put that in loop..ryt ?

Comment: also you will need to copy char temps[100]; to above the fgets.

Comment: Yeah, the fget part works fine and I can store all the values into banned. But I'm running into problems when I try to convert the strings in banned into lower case

Comment: Actually, what you are doing in last 4 lines of code is that...you are adding the first letter of each string in banned to temp after converting it to lower case letter.

Comment: That's the part of the code I'm having trouble with, which is why I asked this question :P. I want to convert the current string in banned to lowercase but right now the results are not coming out the way I expected.

Comment: then you can inter ate through all the string in banned and call this method to lower it and assign to temp or use as required.

Comment: char *strtolower(char *s){char *d = (char *)malloc(strlen(s));while (*s){*d = putchar(tolower(*s));d++;s++;}return d;}

Comment: @Piglet:I have updated the code. You can use it or alter if needed.

Comment: @Piglet: I have updated the code again, removed the putchar in strtolower.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
char temps[100];
size_t i;

for(i = 0; temps[i] != '\0'; i++)
  temps[i] = tolower(temps[i]);
```